# Roslyn - Can't find SyntaxNode.ReplaceNode()

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh543922.aspx , I'm trying to use the ReplaceNode method that should be in the SyntaxNode class.

The thing is, I have this error: "Roslyn.Compiler.CSharp.SyntaxNode does not contain a definition for 'ReplaceNode'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ReplaceNode` is actually an extension method (so that it can return the type passed in).  Make sure you have `using Roslyn.Compilers;` and `using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with that version of the CTP. Others are having the same issue, such as http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOTP-4774 or http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DOTP-4836 .